# Apache version 2.2 and security vulnerabilities

Tags: apache, yum, rhel

A penetration test has recently identified that one of our RHEL(6.7) servers running Apache 2.2.15 is vulnerable on a number of points and needs to be updated to the latest version 2.4. I have run yum update and it says that there are no packages marked for update. I understand that I will need to download the updates manually. There are a few questions I have around the requirement to upgrade Apache.

1. I am up to date on the 2.2 version tree. Does this mean that any security patches made to version 2.4 will be back patched to version 2.2.X as well?
2. I am running PHP (version 5.3.3) and MySQL (version 5.1.73) - will these be affected by upgrading the Apache version (Google tells me that there is no problem on both fronts - but I thought I'd ask before I started down this route).
3. If you experts tell me that I have no other choice but to upgrade, then I'm planning on using the instruction set here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138899/centos-install-using-yum-apache-2-4

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Maybe you should check the 2.2 change logs to see if the particular security flaws identified have been fixed in that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the 2.4 source code from the Apache site and compile it. There's a setting which will configure for RedHat:

`--enable-layout=RedHat`

This setting will configure the paths for executables, configuration files, libraries etc in one go.

The following should be a reasonable starting point for a configuration line:

```
sh ./configure --enable-layout=RedHat --enable-mods-shared=all
```

then perform a `make` and `make install`

Do the same with a newer version of PHP (5.3.29 is available in the "old downloads" section, but try a newer version. Check the changes first though) and your problems should be lessened. Finally, MySQL or MariaDB is available for download and compilation too

**Obviously, try all of this on a test machine first** and back everything up. Your test machine should be as close as possible to your production machine. If you use something like VirtualBox to try it, you can take a snapshot at each point of the process and rollback if something goes wrong